Background Image Not Displaying on Smaller Screens
I’m having trouble with a background image not displaying correctly on smaller screens in a Tailwind CSS-based project. The image is correctly showing up on larger screens, but it's not visible or covering the container as expected on smaller devices.
HTML HERO SECTION
  <!-- hero -->
      <section
        class="hero min-h-[640px] xl:min-h-[840px] bg-hero bg-center lg:bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-fixed xl:rounded-bl-[290px] relative z-20" id="Home"
      >
        <div class="container mx-auto">
          <!-- text -->
          <div
            class="hero__text md:w-[567px] flex flex-col items-center text-center xl:text-left lg:items-start"
          >
          <div>
            <h1 class="h1 custom-gradient mb-8 break-words">
              Instant Cash Offer for Your Home
            </h1>
            <p class="mb-8 text-first-onPrimary">
              Sell Fast, No Fees or Commissions. We Buy in Any Condition!
            </p>
          </div>
            <form
              action="/submit"
              method="POST"
              class="flex flex-col lg:flex-row gap-4 min-w-[200px]"
            >
              <!-- Property Address Input -->
              <div class="mb-8 mx-auto xl:mx-0 inline-flex items-center">
                <div class="relative">
                  <label for="property-address" class="sr-only"
                    >Enter Property Address</label
                  >
                  <i
                    class="ri-home-line absolute left-2 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-400"
                  ></i>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="property-address"
                    name="property_address"
                    placeholder="Enter Property Address"
                    class="btn btn-secondary ring-1 ring-gray-200 outline-none focus:ring-8 focus:ring-first-onPrimary focus:text-second-secondary"
                    onfocus="this.previousElementSibling.style.display='none';"
                    onblur="if(this.value===''){this.previousElementSibling.style.display='block';}"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Phone Input -->
              <div class="mb-8 mx-auto xl:mx-0 inline-flex items-center">
                <div class="relative">
                  <label for="phone" class="sr-only">Phone</label>
                  <i
                    class="ri-smartphone-line absolute left-2 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-400"
                  ></i>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    id="phone"
                    name="phone"
                    placeholder="Phone"
                    class="btn btn-secondary ring-gray-200 outline-none focus:ring-8 focus:ring-first-onPrimary focus:text-second-secondary"
                    onfocus="this.previousElementSibling.style.display='none';"
                    onblur="if(this.value===''){this.previousElementSibling.style.display='block';}"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Submit Button -->
              <button
                type="submit"
                class="btn btn-primary inline-flex mx-auto xl:mx-0 items-center"
              >
                GET FREE OFFER
                <i class="ri-arrow-right-line text-first-onPrimary"></i>
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

Tailwind Configuration(tailwind.config.js)
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['*.{html,js}', './index.html'],
  theme: {
    container: {
      padding: {
        DEFAULT: '15px',
      },
    },
    screens: {
      sm: '640px',
      md: '768px',
      lg: '960px',
      xl: '1200px',
    },
    fontFamily: {
      primary: 'DM Serif Display',
      secondary: 'Jost',
    },
    backgroundImage: {
      hero: 'url(/assets/hero/Background.png)',
    },
    extend: {
      colors: {
        first: {
          primary: '#40B750',
          primaryLight: 'rgba(249, 238, 216, 0.3)',
          onPrimary: '#EFD59E',
          primaryContainer: '#85D08F',
          onPrimaryContainer: '#F9EED8',
          customGradient:
            'linear-gradient(to right, #85D08F 17%, #85D08F 31%, #EFD59E 46%)',
          hover: '#E0E0E0',
        },
        second: {
          secondary: '#0E0E0E',
          onSecondary: '#FEFEFE',
          secondaryContainer: '#CDE1CF',
          onSecondaryContainer: '#D9D9D9',
        },
        accent: {
          default: '#FF5733', // Default accent color
          secondary: '#33CFFF', // Secondary accent color
          hover: '#E0E0E0',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};


Issue:

On Desktop: The background image appears correctly and covers the section as expected.

On Smaller Screens: The image is not visible on smaller screen devices from the user persepctive, but upon testing if its visible in different browsers in  development, it appears.


Steps I Have Attempted:

Verified Image Path:


Confirmed that the image path in the bg-hero class is correct and the image is accessible.


Checked Tailwind CSS Output:


Verified that the .bg-hero class is correctly defined in the output CSS file generated by Tailwind.


Tested CSS Classes:


Removed lg:bg-cover to see if it affects the background image.
Applied bg-cover directly to see if it resolves the issue on all screen sizes.


Reviewed Responsive Design:


Ensured that Tailwind's responsive classes are correctly applied and not conflicting.

Checked for any media queries in custom CSS that might be overriding Tailwind classes.



Used Developer Tools:


Inspected the element with the .hero class in browser developer tools to confirm which styles are applied and if any are missing or overridden.

Screenshot of issue:
On phone devices

One desktop devices

Questions:

How can I ensure to have the picture appear on the user mobile device?

Are there any other common issues or pitfalls with Tailwind CSS background images that I might be missing?



Is this still an issue? The website seems to work now. If not, please create a minimal reproducible example

Yes, it is still an issue. The image loads on desktop but not smaller devices.

So this is not correct?
